# Error while Deployment of spring application on JBoss

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-integration

When I am trying to run my application on jboss, I am getting following stack trace, My application needs database connection at the start of application I am using **hibernate, spring integration** and my database is **mysql**. my database details correct. is there anything I am missing ?

```
 2017-01-06 12:12:23,933 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) MSC000001: 
    Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./ZealWay: 
    org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./ZealWay: 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
    Error creating bean with name 'webController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'transactionManagerService':
    Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'gatewayFacade':
    Error creating bean with name 'gatewayFacade': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'gatewayRouter':
    Error creating bean with name 'gatewayRouterImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'gatewayAquirers': 
    Error creating bean with name 'gatewayAquirers' defined in class path resource [com/iz/zw/configuration/GatewayAquirerConfig.class]:
    Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
    Failed to instantiate [java.util.HashMap]: Factory method 'gatewayAquirers' threw exception; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction;
    nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection;
```

**Datasource configuration code**

```
@Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws IllegalStateException, PropertyVetoException {
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClass(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUser(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        dataSource.setInitialPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("jdbc.initial.pool.size"))); 
        dataSource.setMinPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("jdbc.min.pool.size"))); 
        dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("jdbc.max.pool.size"))); 
        return dataSource;
    }
```

Comment: ` Unable to acquire JDBC Connection;` : you have some problems with DB connection. Maybe it just isn't exposed properly over JNDI...

Answer (score 0):

In your GatewayAquirerConfig you have not defined the bean gatewayAquirers.  You probably have:

```
@Autowired
GatewayAquirers gatewayAquirers;
```

Somewhere but GatewayAquirers does not have a @Component or @Service or is not being picked up in the package scan.

Comment: but when I am deploying it on Tomcat it's working fine..!

Comment: Is you database connection correct on the JBoss?  How do you connect to the database?  Your datasource config.

Comment: added my datasource configuration